# Spring integration using 1 channel for two different proccesses

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a problem where I cannot set up process to go to both channels in parallel, it either goes one or another. I have one `ServiceActivator` and one `Transformer` that have the same input channel `objectOutputChannel`. After going to the `processChannel` it should go to both but instead it goes only one of them and it is different in each request. What can I do to make it working the way I want?

```
    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter channelAdapter(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final MsgReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new MsgReceivingChannelAdapter();
        adapter.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(messageChannel());
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outputChannel")
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler messageHandler(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        final MsgSendingMessageHandler handler = new MsgSendingMessageHandler();
        handler.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "objectOutputChannel")
    public AmqpOutboundEndpoint objectOutboundEndpoint() {
        return Amqp
                .outboundAdapter(rabbitTemplate)
                .exchangeName(objectExchange)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "messageChannel", outputChannel = "loggingChannel")
    public ObjectToStringTransformer loggingTransformer() {
        return new ObjectToStringTransformer();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "loggingChannel")
    public void loggingService(String message) {
        messageLogger.info(message);
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "messageChannel", outputChannel = "processChannel")
    public ObjectDeserializer objectDeserializer() {
        return new ObjectDeserializer();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "processChannel", outputChannel = "objectOutputChannel")
    public MyObject processService(MyObject object) {
        return objectService.check(object);
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "objectOutputChannel", outputChannel = "outputChannel")
    public ObjectSerializer objectSerializer() {
        return new ObjectSerializer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "loggingChannel")
    public MessageChannel loggingChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name = "outputChannel")
    public MessageChannel outputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageChannel")
    public MessageChannel messageChannel() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name = "objectOutputChannel")
    public MessageChannel objectOutputChannel() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel());
```

**DEBUG LOG FOR CASE A** - Doesn't go into `objectOutboundEndpoint()` and go into `objectSerializer()`

```
2021-02-09 11:23:40.221 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Message received GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:40.223 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'messageChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@42f22995'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:40.225 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : bean 'objectTcpController.loggingTransformer.transformer.handler' received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:40.225 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'loggingChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@2b87581'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:40.225 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@5bf95bee] (objectTcpController.loggingService.serviceActivator.handler) received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:40.231 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@5bf95bee] (objectTcpController.loggingService.serviceActivator.handler)' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:40.233 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'loggingChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@2b87581'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:40.233 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : bean 'objectTcpController.objectDeserializer.transformer.handler' received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:40.258 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'processChannel'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:40.258 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@44e043f] (objectTcpController.processService.serviceActivator.handler) received message: GenericMessage [payload=..]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.383 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'objectOutputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/integration/spring/ObjectIntegrationConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@6f8f8a80'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.385 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : bean 'objectTcpController.objectSerializer.transformer.handler' received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.388 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'outputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@66434cc8'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.388 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] .i.h.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper : bean 'objectTcpController.messageHandler.serviceActivator.handler' received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.388 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : bean 'messageHandler'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@38499e48' received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.389 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] .i.h.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper : handler 'bean 'objectTcpController.messageHandler.serviceActivator.handler'' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.390 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'outputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@66434cc8'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.390 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'objectOutputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/integration/spring/ObjectIntegrationConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@6f8f8a80'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.391 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'processChannel'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:23:42.391 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'messageChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@42f22995'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
```

**DEBUG LOG FOR CASE B** - Doesn't go into `objectSerializer()` and go into `objectOutboundEndpoint()`

```
2021-02-09 11:28:19.173 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Message received GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:19.173 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'messageChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@42f22995'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:19.173 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : bean 'objectTcpController.loggingTransformer.transformer.handler' received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:19.174 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'loggingChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@2b87581'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:19.174 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@5bf95bee] (objectTcpController.loggingService.serviceActivator.handler) received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:19.174 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@5bf95bee] (objectTcpController.loggingService.serviceActivator.handler)' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:19.174 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'loggingChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@2b87581'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:19.174 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.t.MessageTransformingHandler       : bean 'objectTcpController.objectDeserializer.transformer.handler' received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:19.175 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'processChannel'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:19.175 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler   : ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@44e043f] (objectTcpController.processService.serviceActivator.handler) received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:22.572 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'objectOutputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/integration/spring/ObjectIntegrationConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@6f8f8a80'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:22.572 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.a.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint    : bean 'objectOutboundEndpoint'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/integration/spring/ObjectIntegrationConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@1a5b8489' received message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:22.574 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] s.i.m.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher : headerName=[ip_tcp_remotePort] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2021-02-09 11:28:22.574 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] s.i.m.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher : headerName=[ip_connectionId] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2021-02-09 11:28:22.574 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] s.i.m.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher : headerName=[ip_localInetAddress] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2021-02-09 11:28:22.575 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] s.i.m.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher : headerName=[ip_address] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2021-02-09 11:28:22.575 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] s.i.m.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher : headerName=[history] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2021-02-09 11:28:22.575 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] s.i.m.AbstractHeaderMapper$HeaderMatcher : headerName=[ip_hostname] WILL be mapped, matched pattern=*
2021-02-09 11:28:22.635 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.a.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint    : handler 'bean 'objectOutboundEndpoint'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/integration/spring/ObjectIntegrationConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@1a5b8489'' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:22.635 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'objectOutputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/integration/spring/ObjectIntegrationConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@6f8f8a80'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
2021-02-09 11:28:22.639 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'processChannel'', message: GenericMessage [payload=..]
2021-02-09 11:28:22.639 DEBUG 8964 --- [pool-4-thread-3] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'messageChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/controllers/ObjectTcpController.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@42f22995'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is not about an `objectOutputChannel` or `messageChannel` since they are both of `PublishSubscribeChannel` class instances. What you describe is about some `DirectChannel` with its round-robin default dispatching strategy. But since we don't several subscribers to direct channels you show us, then the problem is somewhere else.

I suggest you to turn on [Message History](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#message-history) and investigate DEBUG logs for `org.springframework.integration` category to see how your messages travel through the flow. And there you can figure out which of the channels is guilty.

What you show in the code snippet is correct and doesn't look like it is correlated with what you describe...

**UPDATE**

This is what we see in your logs:

```
o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'objectOutputChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/company/demo/core/integration/spring/ObjectIntegrationConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@6f8f8a80'', message: GenericMessage [payload=...]
```

So, your `objectOutputChannel` is really a `DirectChannel` instance and its bean is declared in the `ObjectIntegrationConfiguration`.  If that configuration is not what what you show in the question, then you have a "bean definition override" race condition and your `PublishSubscribeChannel` is overridden with that `DirectChannel`. Please, revise your project configuration and try to find where else you declare that `objectOutputChannel` bean.

Comment: I updated the question with relevant debug logs. It seems like it get messed up while trying to go to `objectOutputChannel`.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.